# Error '1004' in excel VBA, but occasionally works fine

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I keep getting a

"Run-time error '1004' 
 Application- defined or object defined error."

in reference to these lines.

```
Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("C12").Value = (y & "'' Ream")

Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("D12").Value = count * 31.5

Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("E12").Value = daily * 31.5
```

The thing is this code was working before I closed the file and reopened. Also, if I rearrange the lines sometimes they work. I tried changing the "count" and "daily" variables to equal "12" then have them processed in the above code and it still returned the error.

I have looked at multiple answers for this error code, and have tried multiple things mentioned in those posts, but nothing worked. I appreciate all feedback, thank you.

p.s. I am aware that the code in the "If" statement is crap, I'm still working on it. but the code did work in the state that the "if" statement is in now.

```
Sub Update_Last()

Worksheets("5001 Prog").Unprotect "Welcome1"
Worksheets("Drill Log").Unprotect "Welcome1"

Dim w As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As String

    w = 39
    x = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("E39").Value
    y = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("E39").Value
    z = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("D39").Value

If z = Worksheets("Variables").Range("H10").Value Then

     Do Until Not x = y


            y = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("E" & w).Value

            w = w + 1

            z = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("D" & w).Value
        Loop
ElseIf z = Worksheets("Variables").Range("H14").Value Then

    Do Until Not x = y


            y = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("E" & w).Value

            w = w + 1

            z = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("D" & w).Value
        Loop


Else

            w = w + 1
            z = Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("D" & w).Value


End If


Dim count As Integer
    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Pass Type]"), "Ream", Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Size]"), y)


Dim daily As Integer
    daily = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Pass Type]"), "Ream", Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Size]"), y, Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Foreman]"), Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("B5").Value, Worksheets("Drill Log").Range("Drill_Log[Date]"), Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("E4").Value)


Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("C12").Value = (y & "'' Ream")

Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("D12").Value = count * 31.5

Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("E12").Value = daily * 31.5



Worksheets("5001 Prog").Protect "Welcome1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying your worksheets (i.e. **`Dim oW as Worksheet: Set oW = Worksheets("5001 Prog")`**). Then use `oW.Range...`. When you get to the line that throws the error, check `oW` state and values for your variables. Also, use `Option Explicit`.. it will help to eliminate undefined variable issues

Comment: If you don't mind, how do you check the state and values, what do you mean?

Comment: Qualify you worksheets like this (presuming that your worksheets are in the same workbook): `Dim oProg As Worksheet: Set oProg = Thisworkbook.Worksheet("5001 Prog")`. `Dim oDL as Worksheet: Set oDL = Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Drill Log")`. Now Replace all **Worksheets("5001 Prog") with oProg and Worksheets("Drill Log") with oDL**. When you get to the statement that throws the error, right click on `oProg` and add it to the watch window (do same for `oDL`). In watch window, check if its an object. Do the same with your variables (add to watch window) and check their values